# Como converter um projeto de VB6 (.vbp) para VB.NET (.vbproj)?

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-basic-6, basic

Eu descompilei um aplicativo em VB, só que não era .NET, era VB6. Eu gostaria de saber como converter, pois já usei o VbTo Converter e ele crashou em um dos arquivos.
 Aguardo rapidamente respostas :/

Comment: A princípio só programando de novo.

Answer (score 1):

Esse artigo mostra o que é possível fazer para migrar de VB6 para .NET:
[Estudo de Caso: Migração de um grande aplicativo VB6 para .NET](https://www.infoq.com/br/news/2010/01/Migrating-VB6-to-.NET)

O autor cita algumas ferramentas, portanto não vou repetir aqui.

[Essa ferramenta da Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9639) gera um relatório do que deverá ser alterado na migração.

Mas dificilmente uma ferramenta vá migrar seu código sem nenhum erro, dependendo da quantidade de código é melhor fazer manualmente.